# Trying to install various packages, but the error statement : package has non-zero exit status appears. The R version is 4.0.5 on Xubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

```
Installing package into ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘RcppEigen’, ‘pbkrtest’, ‘lme4’, ‘car’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppEigen_0.3.3.9.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1633360 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/pbkrtest_0.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 246327 bytes (240 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 240 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-26.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3297635 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/car_3.0-10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 501293 bytes (489 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 489 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/olsrr_0.5.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1801348 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-RcppEigen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppEigen’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/lme4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
* removing ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/pbkrtest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘lme4’ are not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/car’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘olsrr’
* removing ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/olsrr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘olsrr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpRbo9JR/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: `Try removing ‘/home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-RcppEigen’` Have you tried that?

Comment: yeah tried your suggestion @Phil but the problem persists, Actually the package in question is olsrr but its installation brings in 00LOCK-RcppEigen

Comment: The problem got resolved after                                                                                                                                                                    rm -rf /home/jyoti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-RcppEigen and reinstalling the desired package but the same problem persists as I am trying to install package semPlot